# ValueError: ParentedTree.read(): expected 'end-of-string' but got '(:'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, allennlp

Here is a step-by-step code to debug the error I'm getting:

```
from nltk.tree import ParentedTree

teststr = 'a) Any service and handling fee imposed on customers by Used Motor Vehicle Dealers subject to these Rules: \r\n        1) shall be charged uniformly to all retail customers; \r\n        2) may not be presented as mandatory in writing, electronically, verbally, via American Sign Language, or via other media as mandatory; nor presented as mandatory or mandated by any entity, other than the Arkansas Used Motor Vehicle Dealer who or dealership which is legally permitted to invoice, charge and collect the service and handling fee established by these Rules; \r\n        3) must follow the procedures for disclosure set out by these Rules.'

#Using ALLENNLP's parser
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
conspredictor = Predictor.from_path("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/elmo-constituency-parser-2018.03.14.tar.gz")


treestr = conspredictor.predict(sentence=teststr)['trees']

ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring(treestr)
```

Here is the error I'm receiving with the traceback:

```
<ipython-input-391-f600cbe3ff5e> in <module>

         10 treestr = conspredictor.predict(sentence=teststr)['trees']
         11 
    ---> 12 ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring(treestr)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tree.py in fromstring(cls, s, brackets, read_node, read_leaf, node_pattern, leaf_pattern, remove_empty_top_bracketing)

        616             if token[0] == open_b:
        617                 if len(stack) == 1 and len(stack[0][1]) > 0:
    --> 618                     cls._parse_error(s, match, 'end-of-string')
        619                 label = token[1:].lstrip()
        620                 if read_node is not None: label = read_node(label)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tree.py in _parse_error(cls, s, match, expecting)

        677             offset = 13
        678         msg += '\n%s"%s"\n%s^' % (' '*16, s, ' '*(17+offset))
    --> 679         raise ValueError(msg)
        680 
        681     #////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ValueError: ParentedTree.read(): expected 'end-of-string' but got '(:'
            at index 273.
                "...es))))))) (: :) (S (..."
                              ^
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! The question you're asking is a little unclear. You should try to include some more details about what you're asking. To maximize your chances of getting the help you need you can check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which just gives some tips on how to write a more approachable question.

Comment: Hello. I updated the title and edited the body to display the error traceback. I'm receiving the error shown and not able to debug the error. Any help received would be appreciated. Thanks!